# С какой буквы "вселенная"?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

С прописной или строчной слово "вселенная" в таком контексте?

**Спустя много лет [В/в]селенная свела нас вместе.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выбираем вариант: **Спустя много лет вселенная свела нас вместе.**

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

**ВСЕЛЕННАЯ,** 1. [Как термин ― с прописной буквы] Вся система мироздания, весь мир. Строение Вселенной. Тайны Вселенной. Во всей вселенной ни звука (о полной тишине вокруг). 2. Вся земля, все страны. Объехать всю вселенную. Кричать на всю вселенную.

Итак, с прописной буквы пишется **астрономический термин**.  В переносном значении ― это весь окружающий мир. Обычно пишется **со строчной буквы**, даже если речь идет **о высшей силе**.  В то же время орфография позволяет использовать прописную букву в словах **особой важности**, но здесь это будет **авторским вариантом.**

**Примеры:**

Он поцеловал её, поцеловал с таким жаром, что **вся вселенная** показалась ей в огне горящею! [Н. М. Карамзин. Бедная Лиза (1792)]

Это была очень неловкая секунда, очень. Но **вселенная** пришла мне на помощь. Я услышал зуммер. [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)]

Comment: В ваших примерах значение очевидное. Это не "мир", то есть заглавная неуместна. А тут - не знаю...

Comment: Вселенная свела нас вместе, вселенная пришла на помощь - разве здесь не один смысл?

Comment: Не знаю. Что имел в виду Пелевин, знаю. А что - автор? Впрочем, он уже ваш ответ принял, так что смысла обсуждать не вижу.

Comment: Мой ответ допускает оба варианта на авторское усмотрение.

Comment: Нет. С со строчной только один. По Лопатину: Вселенная (космос) и  вселенная (земля). Если у автора значение "Провидение", то это космос, мироздание, первое значение. С заглавной.  У Пелевина значение скорее всего земное, материальное (зуммер). Хотя Вселенная в значении Провидения тоже была бы уместна. А вот ***свести*** может как Провидение, Рок  -  высшая сила, так и что-то вполне земное (типа "на одном шарике встретились"). Без контекста  нет оснований выбирать одно из двух.

Comment: Рок и провидЕние  часто пишутся со строчной буквы,  но прописная буква тоже возможна.  По Лопатину и Розенталю. Это придание  словам особой важности в конкретном тексте, авторский выбор.   Отсюда следует возможность вариантов.   ПРОВИДЕНИЕ;  ср. Книжн. Высшая божественная сила, направляющая судьбы людей и всего мира к благу; промысел Божий. Как провидению угодно. Храни вас п. Оказаться где-л. волею провидения.

Comment: О чем мы спорим, нее напомните? ))) Вы, похоже, просто вываливаете набор всяких сведений, без всякой связи с предметом.

Comment: Напоминаю: спорите Вы, я вначале ограничилась короткими и вежливыми ответами на Ваши замечания. И пожалуйста, выбирайте корректные выражения, "вываливать" - это грубо-просторечная и оценочная  речь, такое поведение не приветствуется на форуме.

Comment: Даже не думаю. Я вам высказал свои соображения. Впрочем, если спорю я, тогда и мне решать о чем спор, так? Так вот ваши ответы меня совершенно не устроили.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59947/discussion-between--and-sibylla).

Answer (score 6):

Фраза необычна, только автор знает, какая вселенная имеется в виду и как она могла кого-то свести. Если Вселенная = мир, космос, система мироздания, то заглавная, во всех прочих случаях - строчная.

Мне больше импонирует заглавная, как персонификация некоей высшей силы. Если это не противоречит авторскому пониманию термина, то так и пишите.

Я посмотрел, оборот не такой уж и редкий, но видимо, повторяют его как некий штамп, не вникая в смысл. Тем не менее, похоже, что заглавная используется чаще.